# Apply JAXB annotation dynamically

Tags: java, jaxb

Suppose i have a `BOOK.java` file with the fields(`id`, `name`, `author`) and now while marshalling it to XML file, I want only `id` to be written in XML file but that has to be decided by some condition. So I was thinking to inject `@XmlTransient` annotations to other two fields on that condition at runtime. Is it possible to inject an JAXB annotations at runtime? Can i do that and if i can, how can i do so?

Is there any way other then using javassist to do so ?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017088/exclude-a-field-dynamically-in-jaxb) or are you looking for something different?  If something different can you provide more details on your use case?

Comment: I've deleted that question..I need answer for this..I explain you what my requirement is: suppose i have a BOOK.java file with the fields(id, name, author) and now while marshaling it to xml file, I want only id should be written in XML file but that has to be decided by some condition. So I was thinking to inject XMLTransient annotations to other two fields on that condition. Can i do that and if i can, how can i do so?

Comment: @X.L. Ant,Frank SHearer,Jack, ppeterka, Stewbob...why are you closing my question??? what's wrong with this question

Comment: I have updated our question, perhaps the others based their close votes on it having few details.  I have also voted that it be reopened.

Comment: refer here for [XMLTRANSIENT](http://www.techferry.com/articles/jaxb-annotations.html#XmlTransient)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want something that's not JAXB. JAXB is great when it fits, but it's pretty restrictive in what it allows you to do. Something like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) would probably fit your needs better. You can write a [custom `Converter`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html) that will handle all the logic of whether to write a particular field or not.

Comment: thanks for suggesting me XStream...got it worked...however custom Coverter was not used...i used XStream.omitField() method..

Comment: Sorry, But i got instruction to use JAXB only..As XStream's performance is not as good as JAXB...Can the same functionality  as XStream.omitField() be performed using JAXB?